# Why is NOₓ conversion low at fuel rich conditions in a three-way catalytic converter?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, catalysis

> [image: rich conditions = under stochiometric oxygen]
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> &\text{Oxidation:} &\quad \ce{2 CO + O2 &-> 2 CO2}\\
> & & \ce{``HC" + O2 &-> CO2 + H2O}\\
> & & & \\
> &\text{Reduction:} &\quad \ce{2 CO + 2 NO &-> 2 CO2 + N2}\\
> & & \ce{``HC" + NO &-> CO2 + H2O + N2}
> \end{align}
> $$

$\ce{NO_x}$ conversion is low at oxygen rich conditions (lean operation) because no $\ce{CO}$ or $\ce{HC}$ are available for the reduction.
But why is $\ce{NO_x}$ conversion also low at fuel rich conditions, so an optima exists? Rich conditions lead to high $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{HC}$ emission and that should be perfect condition for $\ce{NO_x}$ reduction.

Comment: It may be affected by the reaction mechanism and kinetics. More fuel rich conditions mean lower NO concentration. If NO reduction rate decreases with NO concentration faster than concentration itself, e.g. if the reaction kinetic is of the 2nd order wrt NO, it will lead to lower conversion efficiency.

Comment: N2 +  02 -> NO this reaction is endotherm.

Comment: why do u say fuel rich conditions mean lower NO concentration. Is it cooler or why?

Comment: do you have some reference i need to read it myself

Comment: For similar reasons, why there is low CH for oxygen rich mixture. No reference available, just applying basic principles.

Comment: hm not sure. HC: there is an other reason. Its because  HC are only partly oxidized, because there is not enough oxygen for total conversion. On the other hand if you don't have good HC conversion. NO conversion should be great, if you look at Reduction reactions of my picture.

Comment: fuel rich means i dont have total complete oxidation of my fuel: as a result i get more CO and HC. And those molecules are needed for the reduction of NO. This is the reason why NO conversion drops at high oxygen level (lean conditions). A lot of oxygen meaning that i already have only H20 and CO2 and no CO and HC

Comment: For fuel rich mixture there is not enough oxygen to create NO, as there is kinetically competing CH oxidation, so NO content is low. If kinetics of the catalytic reduction of NO is d[NO]/dt=k.[NO]^2, then a twice lower NO concentration has four times slower conversion rate.

Comment: kinetics should be something like d[NO]/dt=k.[NO][CO] or am i wrong. Ok sure we can say we get less NO because there not enough O2, but this doesnt explain  the conversion of it.

Comment: We have lower NO concentration but CO concentration is higher?

Comment: Rich mixture=partial only combustion=more CO

Comment: Remember that the catalytic NO reduction need not to be a reaction of the 1st (kinetic) order. If it is higher than 1st order, then efficiency of NO conversion is smaller for lower NO concentrations, which occur for rich mixtures.

Comment: maybe i have a better explaination.. it is a Langmuir–Hinshelwood mechanism
A + S ⇌ AS
B + S ⇌ BS
AS + BS → Products
S= Surface
The best reaction rate is when both AS and BS concentrations are 50/50 A = NO and B = CO so if our NO concentration is low the surface concentration is also low and its not optimal. this would also explain the optima?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactions_on_surfaces?wprov=sfla1